# Why is "Error in projectStar %>% projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>% filter(ssex == : could not find function "%>%<-" coming up?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have downloaded the dplyr package by coding library(dplyr)... why am I getting this response when I attempt the following:

```
projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>%
filter(ssex == "female")
```

response:

```
projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>%
  #dplyr
  projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>%
  filter(ssex == "female")
```

> Error in projectStar %>% projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>%
>   filter(ssex ==  : could not find function "%>%<-"

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code includes two lines of assignment, it looks like you did a poor copy/paste.

Comment: Try *just* `projectStar_female2 <- projectStar %>%
  filter(ssex == "female")`

Comment: I had never thought we could define an operator `%op%<-` and use it this way though!

Comment: That's what `%in%` is! `"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`